# orientability of surface and odd/even no. of punctures

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, orientation

Suppose that T is a surface with Euler characteristic -4.

1. Is it orientable or non-orientable?
2. Does it have odd or even number of punctures (disks)?

Comment: I'm not sure how to figure out the orientability. For 2, with the equation x=2-d-p-2t, I think it would be even when it is orientable since p=0, but when non-orientable x=2-d-p and we do not know p, so can't figure this out.

Comment: x is the euler characteristic, d is the disks or punctures, p is projective plane (caps) and t is the torus (handles).

Comment: @cineel Thanks - done.

Answer (score 1):

If $d=1$ or $d=3$ or $d=5$ then $T$ is non-orientable, as $p$ must be odd.

If $d=6$ then $T$ must be orientable, as $p=0$.

If $d=4$ we can have $t=1,p=0$ orientable or $t=0,p=2$ non-orientable.

If $d=2$ then $T$ can be either, as we could have $t=2,p=0$ orientable or $t=1,p=2 $ or $t=0,p=4$ both non-orientable.

Finally if $d=0$ we could have $t=3,p=0$ orientable, or $t=0,1,2$ all non-orientable.

There isn't really anything else you can say with the given information.